# Orion 1.1 and Proton CEP

Tags: fiware-orion, complex-event-processing

According to https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/deprecated.md, XML has been removed in Orion 1.0. Does this mean Orion 1 can not be used to send notifications to IBM Proton CEP?

Proton CEP supports JSON but not NGSI format. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct: XML support was removed in Orion 1.0, after being deprecated in Oron 0.23.0 (i.e. support was removed more than half a year after being declared as deprecated).

Thus, you have the following alternatives:

1. Wait until Proton CEP implements JSON support (it would be great if Proton development team could provide a date on that).
2. Use Orion 0.28.0 (the last Orion version that supports XML). Have a look to [this piece of documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/deprecated/index.html#using-old-orion-versions) about using old versions.
3. Implement a JSON-to-XML software to convert from one format to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Confirms that from the CEP Proton dev. team. The feature is planned for release 5.4 at this time.
We gave priority to performance and stability issues over this feature due to the work around possible with older Orion version as stated above by fgalan.
Thanks,
- Uri